# Detached entity error in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am posting an array of entities to a controller, all of which I'd like to delete. However, the below code throws an `A detached entity was found during removed MyProject\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity@000000004249c13f00000001720a4b59` error. Where am I going wrong?

```
$doctrineManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach ($form->getData()->getEntities() as $entity) {
    $doctrineManager->merge($entity);  
    $doctrineManager->remove($entity);
}
$doctrineManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use *merge* operation on entities which are in *detached* state and you want to put them to *managed* state.

*Merging* should be done like this `$entity = $em->merge($detachedEntity)`. After that `$entity` refers to the fully managed copy returned by the merge operation. Therefore if your `$form` contains *detached* entities, you should adjust your code like this:

```
$doctrineManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach ($form->getData()->getEntities() as $detachedEntity) {
    $entity = $doctrineManager->merge($detachedEntity);  
    $doctrineManager->remove($entity);
}
$doctrineManager->flush();
```

However, in case that the `$form` does not contain *detached* entities, you should remove the *merge* operation, like this:

```
$doctrineManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach ($form->getData()->getEntities() as $entity) {
    $doctrineManager->remove($entity);
}
$doctrineManager->flush();
```

This image should help you to understand entity state transitions. It is taken from Java Persistence API, but in Doctrine2 it is about the same.

[image: JPA state transitions]

Comment: If one needs to remove entities only if they are already managed, you can also check if they are managed by using `EntityManager::contains` method.

Comment: This is old, but merge is now deprecated - what should happen instead?

Comment: In my case it happens when I was managing entities with multiples entityManagers. Entities getted with one entityManager cannot be removed with another.