# Symfony : Detached entity cannot be removed in test suite w/ phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm actually doing some functionnal testing on my api and I'm facing a problem which I don't really understand.

I want to test an API which interact with a remote web hosting server. The goal is to manage VirtualHosts, DNS zones, database etc...
I have a test remote server and to avoid conflicts, I remove the created stuff after the test (in the `TearDown()` function) and create the base (in the `setUp()` function). In the `setUp()` I also load fixtures in the setup.

After a test which add a child of my main entity, I want to clean the remote server :

```
$service = $this->fixtures->getReference('service-web');
$this->container->get('webmanager')->deleteHosting($service, true);
```

The `deleteHosting()` function deletes all remote stuff (the true parameter is the "force" parameter, which ensure that the function doesn't stop after an error.

The `$service` variable contains my main service entity. I also have in this entity a One-To-Many relationship with `addonDomain`'s entity.
My functionnal test creates an addonDomain.
The test is OK, but when I try to delete my service, the attached entity makes Doctrine yell as hell : `Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: Detached entity AppBundle\Entity\Service\Web\AddonDomain@0000000054814da900000000073c524a cannot be removed`.

I tried a lot of things but none of them works (ie : using the doctrine manager to retrieve the entity instead of using the fixture.

Thanks a lot for your help,
best regards.

SOLVED !
In fact, I'm using the container and the entity manager of the test class and not of the client himself. That was the problem...

Comment: I have the same issue and can't figure out how to solve it :/

Comment: As this happened a year ago, I don't remember well. But as updated in the original post, instead of using `$this->container`, try using `self::$container` in both `setUp()` and `tearDown` methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: I solved with calling `merge` before calling `remove` on the entity. Not sure its the best way but it works! Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: No change when using either `$this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');` or `$this->em = $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');` and not even `em->merge(..)`. My entities were removed only when I was flushing entity by entity instead of a single `flush()`.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is an old question, I had the same problem recently while working with Symfony 4.4 and [Detached entity error in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459470/detached-entity-error-in-doctrine) helped me solve the problem. Basically, as @Can Vural suggested, calling *merge* before *remove* is solving the problem, but the missing bit is that you have to assign the entity again so:

```
$entity = $doctrineManager->merge($detachedEntity);  
$doctrineManager->remove($entity);
$doctrineManager->flush();
```

This solved my problem.

Please keep in mind that `merge` is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine 3: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#bc-break-removed-entitymanagermerge-and-entitymanagerdetach-methods

Comment: `merge` is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine 3: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#bc-break-removed-entitymanagermerge-and-entitymanagerdetach-methods

Answer (score 0):

Ive came accross the same problem and `merge` did not solve it for me in functional test so instead I am querying the entities again and then remove them:

```php
class ControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

  public function testCanGet() {

    $em = static::getContainer()->get(EntitiyManagerInterface::class);
    $entity = new Entity();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request("GET", "/route");
    $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
     
    // Remove entity
    $em->remove($em->getRepository(Entity::class)->find($entity->getId()));
    $em->flush();

  }

 
}
```